# What is this tall houseplant with thin, gold-speckled leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants

My friend had this plant and when he moved, I brought it to my house. I want to know what kind of plant it is.

*Click on photo for full size*

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This plant is a variety of croton, [Codiaeum variegatum](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Codiaeum_variegatum).  there are many varieties of this plant that is native to Indonesia, Malaysia and Australia. This cultivar is related to the "Gold Dust" cultivar.

- They can grow as much as six feet (2 Meters) tall but respond well to hard pruning.
- They benefit from bright diffuse light but can tolerate lower light levels. The plant in the picture appears to have been grown in lower light levels as the lower leaves have dropped off.
- Usual watering practices, water till it drains from the bottom of the pot and then let dry
- New plants can be propagated [using stem cuttings](https://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/ep106)
- typical pest problems are [spider mites](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=spider%20mites)